# JavaFX application is very slow

Tags: user-interface, javafx, information-retrieval

We built an information retrieval engine as part of our course project. We were asked to run our program with JavaFX.

The problem is that the project is very busy and includes: parse documents (460,000 docs and up to 3 million words), add terms to a dictionary and more functions that take time.

The time needed for the project to run without GUI is about 19 minutes; it includes merging post files and load the dictionary from disk to RAM.
The issue is that when we add the GUI, the time is multiplied to reach almost 56 minutes.

We think that we did something wrong in the GUI built:

**Controller**

```
package sample;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.stage.DirectoryChooser;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import main.Indexer;
import main.ReadFile;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Controller {
    public javafx.scene.control.CheckBox checkBox_Stemming;
    public javafx.scene.control.Button btn_start;
    public javafx.scene.control.Button btn_browse_Corpus;
    public javafx.scene.control.Button btn_browse_postfile;
    public javafx.scene.control.Button btn_reset;
    public javafx.scene.control.TextField tf_postfilePath;
    public javafx.scene.control.TextField tf_corpusPath;
    public javafx.scene.control.Button btn_dictionary;
    public TableView table_dic;
    public javafx.scene.control.TableColumn tc_term;
    public javafx.scene.control.TableColumn  tc_tf;
    private Stage mainStage;
    private Indexer indexer;
    private ReadFile rf;

    public void initialize(Stage mainStage) {
        this.mainStage = mainStage;
        mainStage.setMinHeight(600);
        mainStage.setMinWidth(800);
    }

    public String openFile(ActionEvent event) {
        DirectoryChooser chooser = new DirectoryChooser();
        File defaultDirectory = new File("C:\\");
        chooser.setInitialDirectory(defaultDirectory);
        File selectedDirectory = chooser.showDialog(new Stage());
        return selectedDirectory.getPath();
    }

    public void setStopWord(ActionEvent event){
        tf_postfilePath.textProperty().setValue(openFile(event));
    }

    public void setCorpusPath(ActionEvent event){
        tf_corpusPath.textProperty().setValue(openFile(event));
    }

    public void startIndex(ActionEvent event) {
        String corpusPath = tf_corpusPath.textProperty().getValue();
        String postfilePath = tf_postfilePath.textProperty().getValue();

        if(corpusPath.length() > 0 && postfilePath.length() > 0 ){
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            indexer=new Indexer();
            rf= new ReadFile();

            try { 


   indexer.Start(rf,corpusPath,checkBox_Stemming.isSelected(),postfilePath);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long elapsedTime = stopTime - startTime;
            long minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(elapsedTime);
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
            alert.setTitle("Information");
            alert.setHeaderText("Look, an Information Dialog");
            alert.setContentText("Number of documents:"+ main.Indexer.n+"\n"
                    +"Number of uniq terms:"+ "\n"+"Running time:"+minutes+ "minutes\n");

            alert.showAndWait();
        } else if (postfilePath.length() > 0) {
            indexer = new Indexer();
            try {
                indexer.createFinalDictionary(postfilePath);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
            alert.setTitle("Problem");
            alert.setHeaderText("Look, an Information Dialog");
            alert.setContentText("The path are empty or both not. please insert only one path postingfile or corpus");

            alert.showAndWait();
        }
    }

    public void resetIndexer(ActionEvent event) {
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
        alert.setTitle("Information");
        alert.setHeaderText("Look, an Information Dialog");
        alert.setContentText("The dictionary and the postingfile deleted");
        alert.showAndWait();
        indexer = null;
        rf = null;
        tf_postfilePath.textProperty().setValue("");
        tf_corpusPath.textProperty().setValue("");
    }

    public void showDictionary(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("hello");

        /**if(indexer != null) {
            HashMap<String, String> dic = indexer.getDic();
            List<String> sortedKeys = new ArrayList(dic.keySet());
            Collections.sort(sortedKeys);
            for (String k:sortedKeys) {
            table_dic.getColumns().addAll(k);
        } else {
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
            alert.setTitle("Information");
            alert.setHeaderText("Look, an Information Dialog");
            alert.setContentText("The dictionary is empty");
            alert.showAndWait();
        }*/
    }
}
```

**FXML file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>

<AnchorPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="800.0" prefWidth="1200.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1">
    <Button fx:id="btn_reset" layoutX="33.0" layoutY="70.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Reset" onAction='#resetIndexer' />
    <Button fx:id="btn_browse_Corpus" layoutX="129.0" layoutY="112.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#setCorpusPath" text="Browse" />
    <Button fx:id="btn_browse_postfile" layoutX="129.0" layoutY="149.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#setStopWord" text="Browse" />

    <TableView fx:id="table_dic" layoutX="451.0" layoutY="70.0" prefHeight="439.0" prefWidth="427.0">
        <columns>
            <TableColumn fx:id="tc_term" prefWidth="211.20001220703125" text="Term " />
            <TableColumn fx:id="tc_tf" minWidth="2.4000244140625" prefWidth="215.20001220703125" text="tf" />
        </columns>
    </TableView>

    <TextField fx:id="tf_postfilePath" layoutX="204.0" layoutY="148.0" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="218.0" />
    <TextField fx:id="tf_corpusPath" layoutX="205.0" layoutY="111.0" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="217.0" />
    <CheckBox fx:id="checkBox_Stemming" layoutX="125.0" layoutY="74.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Stemming" />
    <Button fx:id="btn_dictionary" layoutX="39.0" layoutY="233.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Dictionary" onAction="#showDictionary" />
    <Button fx:id="btn_start" layoutX="35.0" layoutY="187.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Start" onAction='#startIndex' />
    <Text layoutX="46.0" layoutY="129.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Corpus" />
    <Text layoutX="33.0" layoutY="163.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Posting files" wrappingWidth="75.0" />
</AnchorPane>
```

**Main class**

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("IR2020");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        Controller controller=new Controller();
        controller.initialize(primaryStage);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

I would appreciate your help, thank you.

Comment: might be unrelated to the performance issue, but your useage of fxml is completely wrong (there is no relation between the controller and page loaded) - please make sure to understand the basics of injecting ui via fxml :)

Comment: definitely unrelated: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Comment: The issue might be, that you start your Indexing (a processheavy task) within the GUI Thread, within the eventscope of the method `startIndex` you should start a Thread wich not interrupts the GUI thread. and when this task is done retrieve the informations, via `Platform.runLater(()->{})`

Comment: Asside from the fact that you're running everything on the JavaFX application thread as mentioned by Luxusproblem: JavaFX does of course take up some resources (threads, memory). Depending on how tight those resources are this may be more or less of a problem...

Answer (score 3):

I follow @Slaw and @LuxusProblem answers ; you should create a service whose only role is to execute the instruction `indexer.Start(rf,corpusPath,checkBox_Stemming.isSelected(),postfilePath);`. Then in your controller, you have to start this service then listen to the state of this service ; if it switches to SUCCEEDED, then you can display your message box.

I've implemented a basic service for your code (maybe there will be little mistakes, as I don't know how `Indexer` and `ReadFile` classes are made):

```
package sample;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javafx.concurrent.Service;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;

public class IndexService extends Service<Boolean> {
    private String corpusPath;
    private String postFilePath;
    private ReadFile readFile;
    private boolean stemming;

    public IndexService(String cPath, String pfPath, ReadFile rf, boolean stem) {
        corpusPath = cPath;
        postFilePath = pfPath;
        readFile = rf;
        stemming = stem;
    }

    @Override
    protected Task<Boolean> createTask() {
        return new Task<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            protected Boolean call() throws Exception {
                try { 
                    indexer.Start(readFile, corpusPath, stem, postfilePath);
                    return true;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return false;
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

In your controller, the `startIndex` method will look like this:

```
@FXML
public void startIndex(ActionEvent event) throws InterruptedException {
    String corpusPath = tf_corpusPath.textProperty().getValue();
    String postfilePath = tf_postfilePath.textProperty().getValue();

    if (corpusPath.length() > 0 && postfilePath.length() > 0) {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        IndexService service = new IndexService(corpusPath, postfilePath, rf, checkBox_Stemming.isSelected());
        service.start();

        service.stateProperty().addListener((bean_p, old_p, new_p) -> {
            switch (new_p) {
                case SUCCEEDED:
                    long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    long elapsedTime = stopTime - startTime;
                    long minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(elapsedTime);

                    Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
                    alert.setTitle("Information");
                    alert.setHeaderText("Look, an Information Dialog");
                    alert.setContentText("Number of documents:" + "main.Indexer.n" + "\n" + "Number of uniq terms:" + "\n" + "Running time:" + minutes + "minutes\n");

                    alert.showAndWait();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        });
    } else if (postfilePath.length() > 0) {
        indexer = new Indexer();
        try {
            indexer.createFinalDictionary(postfilePath);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
        alert.setTitle("Problem");
        alert.setHeaderText("Look, an Information Dialog");
        alert.setContentText("The path are empty or both not. please insert only one path postingfile or corpus");

        alert.showAndWait();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to go further, you can even manage exceptions that are thrown into your service. When an error is thrown, your `IndexService` switches to FAILED so you can display it.

On the `IndexService` class, just remove the `try-catch` :

```
    @Override
    protected Task<Boolean> createTask() {
        return new Task<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            protected Boolean call() throws Exception {
                indexer.Start(readFile, corpusPath, stem, postfilePath);
                return true;
            }
        };
    }
```

In your controller, add a case for `State.FAILED` into your service state listener:

```
case FAILED:
    Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
    alert.setTitle("Error");
    alert.setHeaderText("Look, an Information Dialog");
    alert.setContentText(service.getException().getMessage());

    alert.showAndWait();
    break;
```

I hope it will help you :)

Comment: Personally, I would not catch the `IOException` in the `Task#call()` method, but instead let exception propagate. That way the `Service` enters the `FAILED` state and the exception is stored in the `exception` property.

Comment: Yes good idea, I'll update my answer tonight so it can manage the FAILED service state.